# Filtering the lines which are greater than a percentage value

Tags: command-line, grep, sed, awk

Hello i need to filter lines which are greater and equal than 85%.

I need to filter according to Forward: Score line and end of the percentage of that line.

**Example file:**

```
Scores for this hit:
>ocu-miR-191-5p NC_013669.1 181.00  -24.77  2 22    123304956 123304978 20  85.00%  85.00%


   Forward: Score: 181.000000  Q:2 to 22  R:190316850 to 190316872 Align Len (20) (85.00%) (85.00%)

   Query:    3' gtCGACGAAAACCCTAAGGCAAc 5'
                  |||||| | ||| ||||||| 
   Ref:      5' gtGCTGCTATAGGGTTTCCGTTc 3'

   Energy:  -24.910000 kCal/Mol

Scores for this hit:
>ocu-miR-191-5p NC_013669.1 175.00  -23.66  2 21    163478767 163478790 20  85.00%  85.00%


   Forward: Score: 173.000000  Q:2 to 22  R:1340814 to 1340836 Align Len (20) (80.00%) (80.00%)

   Query:    3' gtCGACGAAAACCCTAAGGCAAc 5'
                  ||||| |  ||| ||||||| 
   Ref:      5' caGCTGCCTGCGGGCTTCCGTTa 3'

   Energy:  -27.510000 kCal/Mol
```

The **result** should be like this:

```
>ocu-miR-191-5p NC_013669.1 181.00  -24.77  2 22    123304956 123304978 20  85.00%  85.00%


   Forward: Score: 181.000000  Q:2 to 22  R:190316850 to 190316872 Align Len (20) (85.00%) (85.00%)

   Query:    3' gtCGACGAAAACCCTAAGGCAAc 5'
                  |||||| | ||| ||||||| 
   Ref:      5' gtGCTGCTATAGGGTTTCCGTTc 3'

   Energy:  -24.910000 kCal/Mol
```

I tried these commands,

```
awk '{if($14>=85)print$_}' < output.txt 
awk '$14 >= 85' output.txt
awk - F%) '$14 >= 85' output.txt
```

I search on this website there are questions like mine but those didn't solve my problem the command lines that i tried also took the other line because the line also contain 85% score. . Could you please help me? i just started using ubuntu i don't know very well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk '{RS=">"; FS=" "; original_block=$0; gsub(/\(|\)|%/,""); if ($25 >= 85) print original_block}' example.txt > output.txt
```

**Explaination:**

- `RS=">"` will treat input as blocks starting with `>`.
- `FS=" "` will set your field separator to spaces and tabs to get right field count.
- `original_block=$0` will save the original block with parentheses `()` and percent sign `%` for printing purposes later.
- `gsub(/\(|\)|%/," ")` will remove `()` and `%` so that the number can be matched.
- `if ($25 >= 85)` checks if the value of the number in the 25th field in that block is greater than or equal to `85`.
- `print original_block` prints the whole matching block in its original format.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106904/discussion-on-answer-by-raffa-filtering-the-lines-which-are-greater-than-a-perce).